# Use for loop to count whole numbers from 0 to a number javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, count

I have an html select list from 0-5. I select a number from the list, for example 4, and I want the program to spit out 5. since 0,1,2,3,4 is 5 numbers. Currently my loop is just adding the numbers up to 15. Something is wrong with the logic in my for loop.

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
var topValue = document.getElementById('number').value;
topValue = parseFloat(topValue);
number = 0;
for (n = 0; n <= topValue; n++) {
    number = number + n;
};
document.getElementById('result').value = number;
};
```

Comment: What does `Something is wrong with the logic in my for loop` mean exactly? Could you provide a minimal reproducible example (plunker/jsfiddle)?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading incorrectly, but don't you just want `topValue + 1` then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your doubt correctly but I will try to help:

This is happening because you are adding the value of the variable "n" to the variable "number"...

A for loop receives 3 things (basicly/simplified):

- its start value
- its maximum value (where to stop, usually while the condition is true)
- its "speed" (how big the counter will increase or decrease)

The execution of your loop when topValue is 4:

1. Execution 1: number = (number + n) => (0 + 0) = 0
2. Execution 2: number = (number + n) => (0 + 1) = 1
3. Execution 3: number = (number + n) => (1 + 2) = 3
4. Execution 4: number = (number + n) => (3 + 3) = 6
5. Execution 5: number = (number + n) => (6 + 4) = 10

If you just want to count how many numbers exists between zero (included) and the topValue you just have to put this inside your loop:

```
number++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't need a loop. It will always be one more than the number selected.

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
    var topValue = document.getElementById('number').value;

    topValue = parseFloat(topValue);

    document.getElementById('result').value = number + 1;
};
```